# Why Doesn't jackOptions Work in Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1?

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

I went through the guide to add:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

defaultConfig {
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
```

To my android section of my module's build.gradle file.  I also set the gradle plugin version to 2.2.0-alpha1 and even tried gradle wrapper 2.13.

When I try to compile, I get:

```
Error(105, 0): Gradle DSL method not found: jackOptions()
```

I also tried commenting out jackOptions and using "useJack true", which compiled and created an APK, but I had no classes.dex file.

Why am I getting this error about jackOptions?  What am I missing here?

Comment: try deprecated useJack: `defaultConfig { useJack = true }`

Comment: @pskink - I tried that.  It generated an APK, but I was missing my dex files.  Any thoughts on why that would be?

Comment: no "classes.dex" inside apk?

Comment: Correct.  I have a multi dex APK and both classes.dex and classes2.dex are missing.  Everything else is present (assets, res, arsc, lib, META-INF, etc.)

Comment: hmm, no idea, i'm using it with no probs, maybe clean & fresh build?

Comment: Tried that.  Also tried invalidating caches and restarting, then clean and rebuild.

Comment: btw my `buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc1'`

Answer (score 1):

You should use
 `buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc3"`
and before this you must install it.

Answer (score 0):

May be the buildToolsVersion must > 23. Try it.

Comment: No go.  I've already tried 23.0.2 (and .3) along with 24 rc1.